# iText7 MoveText vs SetFixedPosition different results

Tags: itext7

Why do I get different results when I use `MoveText` vs `SetFixedPosition`? I use the same `x` and `y` value but they print on the page in different location. If I use canvasPage.BeginText can it be formatted to use a width and word wrap

```
canvasPage.BeginText()    
.SetFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD), 21)
.MoveText(X,Y)


Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
.Add(_disclaimer)
.SetFixedPosition(X,Y, canvasPage.W)
.SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA))
.SetFontColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)
.SetFontSize(12)
.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
```

Comment: With `MoveText` you set the coordinates of the start of the baseline of the text you draw. With `SetFixedPosition` you set the lower left corner of the rectangle in which the paragraph is rendered. These are different positions, depending on details like paragraph margins or leading and font descend they can differ considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locations between the cases when you add text onto the canvas manually with low-level operations versus the case when you use high-level layout `Paragraph` objects will be different because `Paragraph` is responsible for multi-line layout and adds necessary margins / spacings for the text to look nice and not overlap with other content. The locations are still different only by a minor offset.

You cannot combine low-level `beginText` operation with high-level layout requirements (wrapping text across lines etc) - this is the responsibility of layout's Paragraph.